# Access async loaded component in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

if I register a component using async loading:

```js
components: {
    pdf: () => import('vue-pdf'),
},
```

How can I access `pdf` (and `pdf`'s methods) in the importing component?

Unfortunately it is not possible to just import the component and use it in `components` later.

Comment: What do you need to access on it?

Comment: I need to access a method of this component.

Comment: Could you give more context? What is the method, how is it used etc. There's likely a better way around this than accessing another component's method directly.

Comment: Normally you access a component's method through an instance of that component.  You are trying to access the class method which will have no component `this` context and is probably not what you want.  Please explain the details of what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [template ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) on the `pdf` component (e.g., named `myPdf`), and access the [`vue-pdf` component's methods](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-pdf#public-methods) in your script via [`$refs.myPdf`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs).

This example adds a button to print the first page of the PDF:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <pdf ref="myPdf" src="/tracemonkey.pdf" />
    <button @click="printFirstPage">Print page 1</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    pdf: () => import('vue-pdf')
  },
  methods: {
    printFirstPage() {
      const DPI = 150
      const pages = [1]
      this.$refs.myPdf.print(dpi, pages)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```